# exporting by year and month from 100 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I've been asked to export data out of 100 tables.

for each table it would be something like this:

```
select * from table1
where datepart(yyyy,table1.DOS)=2011
and datepart(mm,table1.DOS)=01
```

and then:

```
select * from table1
where datepart(yyyy,table1.DOS)=2011
and datepart(mm,table1.DOS)=02
```

etc...

i would need to do this for every YEAR and for every MONTH for every table

i  need to export these data sets to a CSV

can you please give me some guidance on how i can automate this instead of using the IMPORT/EXPORT wizard manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic SQL with sp_msforeachtable. Here is a link with info and examples:

http://weblogs.asp.net/nunogomes/archive/2008/08/19/sql-server-undocumented-stored-procedure-sp-msforeachtable.aspx

Comment: great idea thank you! i have some questions 1. it wouldnt be for every table in the database-just 100 out of 150. how do you do an export through code and not the wizard? how would i loop through every year and month?

Comment: export through code to csv, here is a link: http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=49926. For filtering tables, use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES and parsename() function

Answer (score -1):

My Suggestion - `Window Services` help you out by setting the timing(Scheduling) in `Application Configuration` file