# exporting data from sql server into a CSV using ssms

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I need to export data from several tables in SQL Server 2008 using SSMS. I do *not* want to use the native *Export Data Wizard*; I want to use a query instead.  This means I cannot use `sqlcmd` or `bcp`.

How can I export data out of SQL Server 2008 using a query?

I need it to be comma delimited and double quoted as a text qualifier.

Thanks so much for any guidance/help.

Comment: To be clear, you can use a query in the export data wizard

Comment: @swasheck thank you, i meant to say the reason for a query is because i need to automate this and passing parametersinto query

Comment: possible duplicate of [exporting by year and month from 100 tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11019424/exporting-by-year-and-month-from-100-tables)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could run `xp_cmdshell` to run a `bcp` operation:

```
use [master];

declare @sql nvarchar(4000)
select @sql = 'bcp "select * from sys.columns" queryout c:\file.csv -c -t, -T -S'+ @@servername
exec xp_cmdshell @sql
```

You'd, of course, have to figure out how to format your qualifiers (probably through a [format file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191516.aspx))

EDIT:

Your source query would need to be something along the lines of:

```
SELECT IntValue + '"' + CharValue + '"' FROM TABLE
```

Also, you may need to have this feature enabled

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

Comment: thank you very much. my i CAN do a sqlcmd without a format file? i dont want to use a format file, is this posible?

Comment: sure, but you'll have to put a lot more work in to put in text qualifiers

Comment: great! can you get me started?

Comment: It really just becomes a matter of formatting a query such that it includes `"` where you need it.

Comment: understood! i tried to do the cmdshell but getting SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Unable to open BCP host data-file
NULL

Comment: thanks so much , i saw your update however i am getting the same error

Comment: Could be something along these lines? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlexpress/thread/419e024e-cc8b-4be4-b4f3-07ce3cfdd1f1 or http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/transactsql/thread/31a15a51-f557-499c-96a9-df7faccde98d

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов it is not considered polite to ask people here to login to your box for a gotomeeting to review your code. We need interaction to occur here on this site, so that people can have answers _for their problems_. Encouraging someone to come login to your box doesn't help the next person who has this same problem. And if your problem is that unique, maybe you're working on solving the wrong problem?

Answer (score 11):

You can easily create CSV output from SSMS, however it does not do quoting so you may want to choose a format like Tab delimited instead in step 6:

1. Open a new query window.
2. Create your SQL query.
3. Right click in the query window.
4. Choose Query Options...
5. Choose Text under Results.
6. Change the Output format: to Comma delimited.
7. Change the Maximum number of characters displayed in each column to 8000 or an appropriate value.
8. Click OK.
9. Right click in the query window.
10. Choose Results To and Results to File.
11. Execute your query.
12. Choose a file name and location.
13. Click Save.

Comment: i need this automated because i need to pass parameters into the query

Answer (score 3):

Creating a text file using a SQL query is not possible. SQL is meant only for fetching,parsring,updating(etc) the data from the database. You need to have sytem executables/dlls to write to a file.
Is there a specific reason why you want to use a SSMS to export the results produced to a csv? Why don't you use SSIS to generate the results for a csv?

If you use SSIS to do this you create a package to export the information and then you schedule the package in a job to run when ever you want it to.

Comment: thank you - how would i pass parameters into a query this way?

Comment: If you adopt the SSIS approach, a simple select query will do the task. See [this](http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2008/07/23/ssis-exporting-data-to-a-text-file-using-a-package/) if you wish to learn how to do this using SSIS.

Answer (score 1):

To export into an EXISTING excel file:

```
insert into OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
'Excel 8.0;Database=D:\testing.xls;', 
'SELECT * FROM [SheetName$]') select * from SQLServerTable
```

This is dated, but I believe it is still valid.

http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=49926

Cheers!

Comment: No. However, you could use automation to change the xls to csv.  Why CSV over xls?

Comment: xls will not support the amount of rows that i need

Answer (score -1):

You could write a select spiced up with insert.

For instance:
select 'insert into TargetTable values(id, name) values ('''+ id +''','''+ name +''')' from SourceTable